# deleting conda environment safely?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm new to anaconda and conda. I have created an identical environment in two different directories. Is it safe to just delete the env folder or the environment that I no longer need, or do I need to do something in the anaconda prompt to remove the environment thoroughly? I'm not sure if creating an environment in a local folder leaves a trace in the registry or somewhere else in the computer that needs to be removed too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

Comment: This is the recommended way. Howver, deleting the folder has the same effect.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is

```
conda env remove --name myenv
```

Effectively no difference from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61031882/570918), but personally I prefer to use `conda env` commands when operating on whole envs, and reserve `conda remove` for managing individual packages.

The difference between these and deleting the folder manually is that Conda provides action hooks for when packages are removed, and so allows packages to execute `pre-unlink` and `post-unlink` scripts.